# compare between two excel files with a macro

Tags: excel, database, vba

I need to compare between two excel files. i have data of Week S-1 and i need to know what are the transformations that happened to my data in the next week S1.

my data is grouped with a called " Code fonction"

For each "Code fonction" i need to know what are the transformations ( modifications, rows added or deleted rows).

i tried to make a code i worked with the logic to compare row per row, and i made the condition that the "code fonction" must be the same in the rows compared. but the code didn't give me the results that i wanted.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strRepFicA As String, strRepFicB As String
Dim wbFicA As Workbook, wbFicB As Workbook, wbFicAna As Workbook
Dim wsFicA As Worksheet, wsFicB As Worksheet, wsFicAna As Worksheet
Dim lgLig As Long, lgCol As Long
Dim lgLigDeb As Long

' Répertoire et Fichier
strRepFicA = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "S-1.xlsx"
strRepFicB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "S1.xlsx"

' Classeur d'analyse
Set wbFicAna = ThisWorkbook
Set wsFicAna = wbFicAna.ActiveSheet

' Vérifier que les fichiers A et B se trouvent dans le répertoire
If Dir(strRepFicA) = "" Or Dir(strRepFicB) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Le fichier A et/ou le fichier B sont introuvables", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Problème de fichiers..."
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Ouverture du fichier A et définition de la feuille de traitement
Set wbFicA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "S-1.xlsx")
Set wsFicA = wbFicA.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Ouverture du fichier B et définition de la feuille de traitement
Set wbFicB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "S1.xlsx")
Set wsFicB = wbFicB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Vider les lignes du fichier d'analyse
wsFicAna.Range("A2:U" & Cells.Rows.Count).ClearContents

' Première ligne d'affichage des résultats dans le fichier d'analyse
lgLigDeb = 2

' Traitement des lignes des 2 fichiers
' Lignes : 2 à 1250
For lgLig = 2 To 7000
    ' Colonnes : D à AO

        ' Une différence est trouvée dans une ligne
        'wsFicA.Cells(lgLig, lgCol).Value <> wsFicB.Cells(lgLig, lgCol).Value
        If wsFicA.Cells(lgLig, 9).Value <> wsFicB.Cells(lgLig, 9).Value And wsFicA.Cells(lgLig, 5).Value = wsFicB.Cells(lgLig, 5).Value Then
            ' Affichage du nom du fichier en colonne A
            wsFicAna.Range("A" & lgLigDeb).Value = wbFicA.Name
            ' Copier la ligne du fichier A dans le fichier d'analyse
            wsFicA.Range("B" & lgLig & ":" & "U" & lgLig).Copy _
                Destination:=wsFicAna.Range("B" & lgLigDeb)

            ' Affichage du nom du fichier en colonne A
            wsFicAna.Range("A" & lgLigDeb + 1).Value = wbFicB.Name
            ' Copier la ligne du fichier B dans le fichier d'analyse
            wsFicB.Range("B" & lgLig & ":" & "U" & lgLig).Copy _
                Destination:=wsFicAna.Range("B" & lgLigDeb + 1)

            lgLigDeb = lgLigDeb + 2

        End If


Next lgLig

' Fermer les fichiers A et B
wbFicA.Close savechanges:=False
wbFicB.Close savechanges:=False

MsgBox "Traitement terminé"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you mean the "THEN" in `If wsFicA.Cells(lgLig, 9).Value <> wsFicB.Cells(lgLig, 9).Value And wsFicA.Cells(lgLig, 5).Value = wsFicB.Cells(lgLig, 5).Value Then` not gives an expected result, maybe try first with two conditions, something like this : `If  wsFicA.Cells(lgLig, 5).Value = wsFicB.Cells(lgLig, 5).Value Then` put at the next line `If wsFicA.Cells(lgLig, 9).Value <> wsFicB.Cells(lgLig, 9).Value Then` the next line `wsFicAna.Range("A" & lgLigDeb).Value = wbFicA.Name` and so  on.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, may its easier saving your data as a .csv and use git diff to handle your transformations. You need to be familiar with git for this though